# Qt webassembly cache

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly

I am beginner in WebAssembly

I want to create a Qt WebAssembly application.

Does Qt WebAssembly have cache?
If I update my application, do I need to clear the cache so my program will update?

Answer (score 1):

A Qt WebAssembly application is just another web asset, the .wasm file and the .js file of your app should be handled from the server side, so cache only updates based on the etag of your file. If you don't set your cache headers, the browser most likely will try to download your whole app. I was involved in the Felgo Web Assembly development, check out or blog post about it https://blog.felgo.com/updates/release-3-5-0-run-qt-apps-in-browser-webassembly-wasm